# AbsoluteLayout not present on latest nventive UNO?

Tags: uno-platform, uno

This code in the xaml file, render's nothing: Please suggest as what to use to position the controls absolutely on the page.

```
<Grid x:Name="gd"> <Canvas Width="{Binding ElementName=gd, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=gd, Path=ActualHeight}"> <Grid Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="100"> <Grid.RowDefinitions> <RowDefinition Height="*" /> <RowDefinition Height="*" /> </Grid.RowDefinitions> <Rectangle Fill="Red" /> <Rectangle Fill="Black" /> </Grid> </Canvas> </Grid>
```

Comment: '''    <AbsoluteLayout>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="10,0">
<TextBlock Text="Text1"/>
<TextBlock Text="Text1"/>
</Grid>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0">
<TextBlock Text="Text1"/>
<TextBlock Text="Text1"/>
</Grid>
 </AbsoluteLayout>'''

Comment: Please don't use comments for adding clarification to questions. Use the [edit] button and edit the question so it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

`AbsoluteLayout` is a naming coming from Xamarin.Forms/MAUI. In the WPF/WinUI/UWP XAML, the analogous layout panel is called `Canvas`.

You can layout its children by setting the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties:

```xml
<Canvas Width="400" Height="400">
   <Button 
         Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="50" 
         Width="100" Height="100" Background="Red" />
   <Border 
         Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="200" 
         Width="50" Height="50" Background="Blue" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: <Grid x:Name="gd"> <Canvas Width="{Binding ElementName=gd, Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=gd, Path=ActualHeight}"> <Grid Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="100"> <Grid.RowDefinitions> <RowDefinition Height="*" /> <RowDefinition Height="*" /> </Grid.RowDefinitions> <Rectangle Fill="Red" /> <Rectangle Fill="Black" /> </Grid> </Canvas> </Grid>

This is not working for UNO framework

Comment: The Grid.RowDefinitions should be under Grid, not under Canvas